# Unable to open HDD partitions after migrating Ubuntu to SSD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I recently migrated my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from HDD to an SSD. The previous ubuntu partition on HDD was 107 Gbytes. The SSD OS boots successfully but some how does not recognize the old HDD partitions. The HDD has partitions as follows in which sda1 being old boot and sda8 as old swap partition.

```
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 106.7G  0 part /media/user/12a213e9-14aa-4b77-bf7c-77e89f242
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0 116.4G  0 part /media/user/7A9428429427FEEF
├─sda6   8:6    0 116.4G  0 part /media/user/98EA0A9DEA0A77B0
├─sda7   8:7    0 116.4G  0 part /media/user/26D81E7ED81E4C85
├─sda8   8:8    0   7.9G  0 part 
└─sda9   8:9    0   1.9G  0 part
```

While migrating I also created swap on SSD. SSD partitions are as follows.

```
sdb      8:16   0 223.6G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0 213.8G  0 part /
├─sdb2   8:18   0   9.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sdb3   8:19   0   200M  0 part
```

While opening HDD partition, I am getting error an 'Could not display 12a213e9-14aa-4b77-bf7c-77e89f242. The file is of unknown type'. Is this happening due to wrong mounting of HDD?

Comment: What do you mean by "opening HDD partition" ? The only way to access the content of a partition (in any meaningfull way for a normal user) is to mount it.

Comment: `cd /media/user/12a213e9-14aa-4b77-bf7c-77e89f242` will bring you into the mounted filesystem.

Comment: @SorenA In files window it showed all different volumes on the computer but when I clicked one to access it I got the error 'Could not display 12a213e9-14aa-4b77-bf7c-77e89f242. The file is of unknown type'.

Answer (score 0):

Could not access it with `cd` either but finally found what was wrong. I attached a USB storage and got error that I do not have necessary permission to show the contents. Doing `sudo chown $USER: /media/$USER/` solved the issue for USB and HDD both.